# 3D figures in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-styles, 3d

Can you advise me some good packages for drawing this one stuff:
[image]

And I'd like to ask for future, what is the most effective method for drawing 3D plot?

Comment: For properly rendered 3D grahics, Asymptote is probably the most capable of the LaTeX-friendly programming languages.  But PSTricks, TikZ or Metapost could all do the diagram you have posted.  There are also many external drawing tools like Dia or GeoGebra that can produce suitable graphics for TeX.  Which is best depends on your skills and patience...

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (14,14);
    \draw (4,4) circle (2cm);
    \draw (2,4) arc (180:360:2cm and 1cm);
    \draw [dashed] (2,4) arc (180:0:2cm and 1cm);
    \draw [-latex,thick] (4,4) -- + (2,0) node [right] {$S_{0}$};
    \draw [-latex,thick] (4,4) -- + (0,2) node [above] {$S^{i}$};
    \draw [dashed] (4,4) -- + (-2,0);
    \node at (2,2.5) {$D^{-}$};
    \node at (2,5.5) {$D^{+}$};
    \node at (3,2.8) {$S^{i-1}$};
    \node at (4.9,5.2) {$x^{1}$};
    \node at (4.3,5.5) {$x_{0}$};
    \draw [-latex,thick] (7,4) -- + (1.5,0) node [above,midway] {$\Psi$};
    \draw (10,4.8) circle (0.8);
    \draw (10,3.2) circle (0.8);
    \node at (9,4) {$S_{0}$};
    \node at (11,5.5) {$S_{1}^{i}$};
    \node at (11,2.5) {$S_{2}^{i}$};
    \draw [-latex,thick] (11.3,2.8) -- + (30:1.5) node [midway,below] {$\beta$};
    \draw [-latex,thick] (11.3,5) -- + (-30:1.5) node [midway,above] {$\alpha$};
    \node at (13.5,3.8) {$(M,x_{0})$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: Here I added the vector inside the sphere. To do so, I used `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}`

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (14,14);
    \draw (4,4) circle (2cm);
    \draw [name path=continuo] (2,4) arc (180:360:2cm and 1cm);
    \draw [dashed,name path=tratteggio] (2,4) arc (180:0:2cm and 1cm);
    \path [name path=lineA] (4,4) -- + (45:1.5);
    \draw [name intersections={of=tratteggio and lineA},-latex] (4,4) -- (intersection-1);
    \path [name path=lineB] (4,4) -- + (225:1.5);
    \draw [name intersections={of=continuo and lineB},-latex] (4,4) -- (intersection-1);
    \node at (4.2,3.8) {$x^{2}$};
    \draw [-latex,thick] (4,4) -- + (2,0) node [right] {$S_{0}$};
    \draw [-latex,thick] (4,4) -- + (0,2) node [above] {$S^{i}$};
    \draw [dashed] (4,4) -- + (-2,0);
    \node at (2,2.5) {$D^{-}$};
    \node at (2,5.5) {$D^{+}$};
    \node at (3,2.8) {$S^{i-1}$};
    \node at (4.9,5.2) {$x^{1}$};
    \node at (4.3,5.5) {$x_{0}$};
    \draw [-latex,thick] (7,4) -- + (1.5,0) node [above,midway] {$\Psi$};
    \draw (10,4.8) circle (0.8);
    \draw (10,3.2) circle (0.8);
    \node at (9,4) {$S_{0}$};
    \node at (11,5.5) {$S_{1}^{i}$};
    \node at (11,2.5) {$S_{2}^{i}$};
    \draw [-latex,thick] (11.3,2.8) -- + (30:1.5) node [midway,below] {$\beta$};
    \draw [-latex,thick] (11.3,5) -- + (-30:1.5) node [midway,above] {$\alpha$};
    \node at (13.5,3.8) {$(M,x_{0})$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]